# How can I cross join dynamically in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, collections, cross-join

I want to create product variations like this image:
[image]

I have tried with static data it works.

```
$collection = collect(["XL", "XXL"]);
return $collection->crossJoin(["1kg", "2kg"], ["Red", "Green"]);
```

But I want to create this dynamically. I have tried this way.

```
$collections = [];
foreach ($request->options as $key => $option) {
  if($key == 0) continue;
  array_push($collections, $option["option_values"]);
}

return $collection->crossJoin($collections);
```

Its return like this image.That is not exact I want. I figured out problem that is $collections is a new array and option values inside this array. So that it's return like this. But I can not solve this problem.

[image]

I have dd my request data.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were on the right track. The way I see it you need something like:

```
// all of my options
$options = [];

// Just store all options in the array
// I am going to assume $option["option_values"] is always an array
foreach ($request->options as $key => $option) {
  array_push($options, $option["option_values"]);
}

// Get the first element so we can use collections
// and the crossJoin function
$start = array_shift($options);
return collect($start)->crossJoin(...$options);
```

The `(...$options)` kind of explodes all elements in the array and sets them as paramenters.

Some people may tell you to use the function `call_user_func_array` which allows you to call a function with its arguments as an array, like so...

```
call_user_func_array('some_function', ['argument1', 'argument2']);
```

Unfortunately I have never used this function. If there is someone with more experience who can implement it, I would like to know how it would be done.